# AmazonS3Client.putObject doesn't work if I call AmazonS3Client.listObjects first

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been trying for a long time to solve this, but without success. I'm using AWS Android SDK to upload files to AWS S3, and sometimes my files upload to the server, others it doesn't. The putObject instruction is executed, but it simply "hangs up" and lock the code execution on that line.

By trying to comment pieces of code to find the source of the problem, I concluded this happens because I call listObjects before any uploads.

I can't remove this listObjects because I need to fetch the file names when the App starts, and any uploads will only take place after the user selected what it wants to upload.

I usually upload photos from my cell, about 1 to 1.3 MB, and it concludes the upload in less than 30 seconds. If I call listObjects it "hangs up". Why is this happenning? Does anybody have a clue of what is going on? Here goes a few lines of my code:

During android onCreate:

```
weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>();        
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(lista_de_baldes.get(0).getName()).withPrefix("Thumbs"));
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries())
    weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.jogo, objectSummary.getKey().replace("Thumbs/", "")));
```

After the user selected a photo to upload (executed during doInBackground from a class that extends AsyncTask to prevent the main thread from freezing):

```
File arquivo = new java.io.File(filePath);
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
    lista_de_baldes.get(0).getName(),
    filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
    arquivo
);
s3Client.putObject(por);
```

They are ulso using the same bucket, same region and the same zone. The objectListing also runs fine.

---

Edit: I "solved" the problem by setting the AmazonS3Client variable again in the upload code. Like this:

```
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
           new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY)
       );
s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.SA_EAST_1));
```

But that doesn't make sense to me, because it was a global variable. Looks like it simples got "locked" after I downloaded the list of objects. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

---

Edit: As requested, here goes more of the code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                   new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY)
                   );
    //mudei de US_WEST_2 para SA_EAST_1 (south america) para acessar um bucket criado em SP/Brazil
    s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.SA_EAST_1));

    lista_de_baldes = s3Client.listBuckets();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>();        
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(lista_de_baldes.get(0).getName()).withPrefix("Thumbs"));
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        File arquivo_thumb = new File(getCacheDir() + File.separator + objectSummary.getKey().replace("Thumbs/", ""));
        weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.jogo, arquivo_thumb.getName().replace(".png", ".jpg")));

        if(arquivo_thumb.exists())
            continue;

        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
            override.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
                    lista_de_baldes.get(0).getName(),
                    "Thumbs/" + arquivo_thumb.getName()
                    );
            urlRequest.setResponseHeaders(override);
            URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest);
                            ...
         }
```

The upload part:

```
     protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(Uri... uris) {

        if (uris == null || uris.length != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        // The file location of the image selected.
        Uri selectedImage = uris[0];

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

        // Put the image data into S3.
        try {                   
            // Content type is determined by file extension.
            File arquivo = new java.io.File(filePath);
            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                    lista_de_baldes.get(0).getName(),
                    filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
                    arquivo
                    );
            por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            s3Client.putObject(por);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is listObjects wrapped in AsyncTask? Do you wait until listObjects finishes? FYI, since Honeycomb level 11, multiple AsyncTask instances are executed sequentially by default.

Comment: No, listObjects isn't wrapped in a AsyncTask. It is simply running on the onCreate method. Nothing is executed until listObjects finishes.

Comment: The AmazonS3Client should not lock putObject if you call listObjects first. I am not aware of locking on the S3 service side. A few things: 1) like you said, AmazonS3Client is intended for reuse. 2) listObjects is a network request. It will block the UI thread. 3) complete code and stack trace (if any) may help us identify the issue for you.

Comment: Edited the question and added more code. listObjects is not being used inside an AsyncTask, at least for now.

Comment: I don't see bizarre thing in your code except the listObjects call that blocks the UI thread. However that shouldn't be the cause of this issue. I tried your code and didn't encounter any problem. Do you see anything interesting in logcat when the 'hang' occurs?

Comment: Hey Vini.g.fer, were you able to resolve this issue? I am also having the same issue where s3Client.putObject(..) just hangs randomly and locks up the code execution. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not really Torri Veganas. I had to use the workaround I described in the first "Edit" of the original post. Also had to leave this aside due to other priorities. Hope the workaround helps!